# Should I use static method or public method ... android

Tags: java, android, oop

I want to create DownloadData class and there implement a method to download the data from my web service !

in this way :

```
public class DownloadData {

public static string getData("url"){  ..... return data;}

}
```

so should I declare the method as static and then i could call it by the class name with out create DownloadData object;
or to "not" declare it as static and then I should create an object to call the method.

edit:
I can't use getData method in several thread if I declare another static fields 
in this way :

```
public class DownloadData {
    static int num=0;
    public static string getData("url"){ 
 ..... return data;}

    }
```

thank you very much

Comment: If you're sure that your app will perform just 1 download at time, you can declare it static

Comment: actually i will perform more than one download, I will use it in a lot of other classes :)

Comment: If several downloads could be performed simultaneously, you should create separate object for each.

Comment: so i can't call the same method in two threads for example, but if I call it more than one time in the same thread it is good, because there is no collision

Comment: that's what I'm talking about :)

Comment: ok that is great, but i just want to know which is better in performance ? if there is no collision !

Comment: practically, there is no difference. Java doesn't copy bytecode of methods to every created object :)

Comment: You can run a static method on several threads without problems if you don't use static class variables. Variables declared within the scope of a static method and parameters are not shared.

Comment: PLEASE SEE THE CODE THAT I EDIT THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your method as static if you don't need your class `DownloadData` to hold any state and you won't need to use an instance of `DownloadData` class anywhere (e.g. to pass it as a parameter).

Don't think about a single method in this class, think about how you're going to use the class as a whole.

Note: state can be also stored in static variables but that means you have only set of values. That may be appropriate in some cases but you would need to be careful in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: yes, actually i want to declare more than one method and all , i intend to declare all of them as static, i just want to know which is better (performance speed memory ) thank you

Comment: @Szymon state data can be stored in static fields, don't they?

Comment: excuse me, what do you mean with "with hold any state" please could you just explains by a code example ?

Comment: Check what stateful and stateless mean. If you have a variable on a class itself, this is the state that the class holds. If the variable is static, there's only one copy of the variable's data. In cases of non-static (instance) variables, every instance of a class has separate data and changing one instance doesn't affect other instances.

Comment: why it is prohibited to declare another instance of DownloadData ?

Comment: @user3516596 Who said it was prohited?

Comment: you said that : " you won't need to use an instance of DownloadData class anywhere " !!!

Comment: In some cases having an instance is useful. In those cases, you shouldn't use static methods. This is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to think about how you will accomplish this. Android recently requires you to do webrequests async now and will error if you don't do it this way. This will limit how you will pull data now.

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

If you are using json and you have it well organized, I would also recommend taking a look at retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/. It is very easy to implement and saves your a lot of work.

Comment: static doesn't mean it cannot be accessed/executed in a thread different from UI

Comment: Correct, I was not saying static shouldn't or couldn't be used. I was just adding more information about the async process so they were better aware of details and could make a more informed decision.